# Primavera V10 - Erro no AbreEmpresa

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Quando tento abrir a empresa usando o método AbreEmpresa, aparece-me o seguinte erro

> 'A referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto.'

Alguém sabe como resolver ? Obrigado.

O código que uso é este:

```vb
  Public bsERP As New ErpBS
    Public plat As New StdPlatBS

    Public p_empresa As String = "DEMO"
    Public p_username As String = "naurio"
    Public p_password As String = "*****"
    Public p_instancia As String = "Default"
    Public p_versao As String = "10.00"
    Public p_plat As String = "EMPRE"

 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim tp As EnumTipoPlataforma = EnumTipoPlataforma.tpProfissional
        If p_plat = "EMPRE" Then
            tp = EnumTipoPlataforma.tpEmpresarial
        ElseIf p_plat = "ERPPLAT" Then
            tp = EnumTipoPlataforma.tpFirst
        End If
        Dim objStdTransac As StdBETransaccao = New StdBETransaccao()

        'ABRE a plataforma para integrar os anexos
        Dim confapl As New StdBSConfApl
        Dim trans As New StdBETransaccao
        With confapl
            .AbvtApl = "ERP"
            .Instancia = p_instancia
            .Utilizador = p_username
            .PwdUtilizador = p_password
            .LicVersaoMinima = p_versao
        End With
        plat.AbrePlataformaEmpresa(p_empresa, trans, confapl, tp)

        bsERP.AbreEmpresaTrabalho(tp, p_empresa, p_username, p_password, objStdTransac, p_instancia)


        '*************************************************************

        If Convert.ToBoolean(bsERP.Base.Clientes.NumeroContribuintesRepetidos("000000000")) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot continue because the NIF for the current entity already exist.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Else
            Dim customer As BasBECliente = New BasBECliente()
            customer.Nome = "naurio"
            customer.Cliente = "nau"
            customer.NumContribuinte = "000000000"
            customer.Moeda = "EUR"
            'customer.EmModoEdicao = If(PriEngine.Engine.Base.Clientes.Existe(txtName.Text), True, False)

            Try
                bsERP.Base.Clientes.Actualiza(customer)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to save client. " & vbLf & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If




        '***********************************************************************


        bsERP.FechaEmpresaTrabalho()
        bsERP.FechaLigacaoBaseDados()
```

Se me conseguirem ajudar a resolver ou um exemplo de usar os motores na no visual studio no asp.net. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se bem entendi estás a fazer uma aplicação web. Se sim recomendo que não uses a API directamente na tua aplicação, e a resposta é simples. Uma aplicação web é uma aplicação *stateless app* o que faz que a cada pedido que faças tenhas de te autenticar e fazer o processo de `AbreEmpresa`, que digamos é uma coisa que tem um custo de performance assinalavél.

Soluções:

- Usares a webapi em vêz da api.
- Criar tu os teus webserviçes que depositam informação numa queuee depois usas um background worker para aceder API. Esse sim pode instanciar e manter em memória a instancia.

Quanto ao teu problema em concreto. O que se passa é que tu não tens todas as assemblies que necessitas publicadas na pasta BIN da tua webapp. Quando usas o ERPBS100 vais necessitar de ter todas as assemblies que compoen a API nessa mesma pasta. Para resolver isso tens de usar um assembly resolver, podes ver aqui como [Assembly resolving in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867087/assembly-resolving-in-asp-net-project-outside-of-bin-folder)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, entendi o que foi explicado e fez sentido para mim para complementar o trabalho. Mas tenho outra questão. Fui ao GitHub utilizei exmplos vossos que estão desenvolvidos em C# e funcionam perfeitamente, Mas e para funcionar em VB.NET o procedimento é o mesmo ? Tentei usar o mesmo procedimento do C# convertendo o código mas aparece-me o mesmo erro que este aqui em cima mencionado.

Comment: Em VB.net podes ter de adptar o resolver, tirando isso deve funcionar sem problema.